# can we display two pages(Account & custom object) in single visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

i have two visual force pages and i have to display those two pages in single visual force page, so can we display two pages (standard & custom object)in single visual force page ? i got this question in recent interview. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include a standard page and visualforce page inside a custom visualforce tab. You can included two visualforce pages inside a single visualforce tab.

```
<apex:page id="thePage">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel">
    <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne">content for tab one</apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use `<apex:include>` visualforce tab to include another visual force page on one visaul force page. visit following link for more details

[Apex:Include](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm)